# Windows10 API or command to show network notification window

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-10, wmi

[image: Show available network window]

Have any API or command to show this window in windows 10

Comment: Yes, i think this is UWP

Comment: I don't know about this contextual menu, but you could open the 'available wifi' panel in the settings app with `Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new System.Uri("ms-settings:network-wifi"))`